# In c# how to dynamically select the type of the generic function to call

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, mono, nested-generics

In C#, I have some generic function. I have a list of dynamic objects with which I want to call the rightly typed function
It works in simple cases, but doesn't compile as soon as templates are nested.
 How to make it work in the nested templates case?

```
void f1<T>(T a )
{
  Console.WriteLine( typeof(T) );
}

void f2<T>(List<T> a )
{
  Console.WriteLine( typeof(T) );
}

void f3<T>(List<List<T>> a )
{
  Console.WriteLine( typeof(T) );
}

[Test ()]
public void TestDynamic()
{
  var l = new List<dynamic>();
  l.Add(3);
  l.Add("hello");
  //This compiles and works fine 
  foreach (var i in l)
    f1(i);
  //prints System.Int32
  //prints System.String

  var l2 = new List<dynamic>();
  l2.Add(new List<int>{3});
  l2.Add(new List<string>{"hello" } );
  //This compiles and works fine
  foreach (var i in l2)
    f2(i);
  //prints System.Int32
  //prints System.String

  var l3 = new List<dynamic>();
  l3.Add(new List<List<int>>{new List<int>{3} });
  l3.Add(new List<List<string>> {new List<string>{"hello" } });
  //This doesn't compile : "The type argument for method f3 cannot be inferred from the usage, try specifying the type arguments explicitly
  foreach (var i in l3)
    f3(i);
}
```

Comment: This works and compiles for me in VS 2010 C# 4.0.

Comment: Works for me too. VS2013 C# 4.5

Comment: I'm under mono / .Net 4.5

Comment: Thanks Martin and Dawid  so it's a mono issue. I reported it to mono's bugzilla.